# I get a Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression CONVERT and CAST

Tags: ms-access

I tried to use this syntax but keep getting errors. I have tried several variations. I want to convert a string column to an integer and verify it is greater than zero

```
SELECT CAST(Columnx AS UNSIGNED) FROM HOLD2 where columnx > 0
```

or

```
 SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMNX,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS CX FROM HOLD2 where cx > 0
```

I get an error message: *Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘CONVERT……*  or *'CAST....*
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT CLNG(Columnx) FROM HOLD2 where CLNG(columnx) > 0` - JET SQL doesn't have the CAST function.  Use CLNG to convert to a Long, CINT to an Integer, CSTR to String.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Also - it won't convert the value, just displays and treats the value as a long rather than text.  The table will still hold the text value as that's what the field type requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access does not use this syntax. Most of the time you can get away with an implicit conversion. If you do need to specify a cast use the [C functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx): [`CInt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [`CLng()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [`CDbl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftekwwt0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [`CDec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx), [`CCur()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astsh4z8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

The closest thing to what you want is CByte but this only goes from 0 to 255 which is small.

You can try something like this and use it in your query. Access doesn't have short circuit logic so you need to use VBA if you want to avoid errors

```
Public Function ConverToPositiveInteger(str As String) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lng As Long
    lng = CLng(str)
    If CStr(lng) = str Then
        If lng >= 0 Then
            ConverToPositiveInteger = lng
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    ConverToPositiveInteger = Null

End Function
```